# First form_tag inside loop never hits the controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, loops

I have a form inside a loop that looks like this:

```
- @templates.each do |template|  
  tr
    td.col-md-2
      = template.kind.capitalize
    td.col-md-9
      = form_tag(add_workout_from_template_path, method: :post) do
        = hidden_field_tag 'date', params[:date]
        = hidden_field_tag 'athlete', params[:athlete]
        = hidden_field_tag 'title', template.title
        = hidden_field_tag 'kind', template.kind
        = hidden_field_tag 'distance', template.distance
        = hidden_field_tag 'duration', template.duration
        = hidden_field_tag 'notes', template.notes
        = hidden_field_tag 'video', template.video

        = submit_tag(template.title, class: 'fake-button')
    td.col-md-1
      = link_to image_tag('cancel.png'),
        template_path(template),
        method: :delete
```

For iteration 2, 3 and 4 it works like a charm. Whenever I click `template.title` the form executes, hits the controller and does what I want. It prints this list and I can click the titles to add them to a calendar:

[image]

However, when I click on the first one (Other 20x ...) it never creates what it should in the controller, it just creates a blank object and redirects. When I try to raise in the controller, it never raises on the first one so for some reason it seems like it is not hitting the controller at all?

What am I doing wrong here?

controller code:

```
def add_workout_from_template
  @athlete = User.find_by(slug: params[:athlete])
  @workout = Workout.create!(
    user: @athlete,
    date: params[:date],
    title: params[:title],
    kind: params[:kind],
    distance: params[:distance] || 0,
    duration: params[:duration] || 0,
    notes: params[:notes],
    video: params[:video]
  )

  redirect_to team_user_workouts_path(current_user.team,
    current_user, athlete: @athlete)
end
```

Comment: do you mind adding the logs from your rails console when you click on the first element ?

Comment: can you also show us how @templates is created ?